# Django - for each field value

Tags: django

I have a question.

In my view, I return a dataset which includes:

- Category
- Product
- Price

I want to say something like the below, where I show UI elements related to a category as a whole.

is it possible?

```
{% for item.category in products %}
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant models and view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly. You would do

```
{% for item in products %}
    ...
    {{ item.category}}
```

Or if item.category is itself an iterable  you can nest loops. If it's the set of related objects you need a `.all` (c.f. python `obj.foo_set.all()` )

```
{% for item in products %}
   ...
   {% for category in item.category.all %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for item in products %}
         {{item.Category}}
         {{item.Product}}
         {{item.Price}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.